# How to add screens in the stack and only navigate to the last screen added so when I go back, I reach the second-last screen and so on

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I conditionally render two separate stacks based on if the user is Authenticated or not.

```
 <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
            <Stack.Screen name={stacks.appStack} component={AppStack} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name={stacks.authStack} component={AuthStack} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

My AuthStack has two login screens Login1 and Login2. When user opens the app he first sees the Login1 screen where he enters details like username password, then on the Login2 screen, the user is asked to enter some more details. Once the user is authenticated, the AppStack is loaded. This works as expected.

Now, when the user signs out of the app, it would conditionally load the authStack as required. But I want to have it such that Login1 and Login2 screens should both get added in that authStack, but the user at first lands on the Login2 screen directly. And once the user swipes right, he/she is able to go to Login1 screen from there.

How exactly do we do this with react-navigation, i.e, put Login1 screen in the stack but don't navigate to it yet, put Login2 screen and navigate to that one first?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by adding another component called AuthenticationRouter that would be at the top of AuthStack. This component would create an array of routes, where routes for Login1 and Login2 were pushed according to the sequence I want, and then this array was passed as routes in the `CommonActions.reset()` method provided by React Navigation in the useEffect of AuthenticationRouter.

For eg, we just create and call the below function in the useEffect of AuthenticationRouter.

```
const determineLoginDisplay = () => {
    const routesBasedOnFlags = getRoutesBasedOnFlags();
    const resetStack = CommonActions.reset({
      index: routesBasedOnFlags.length - 1,
      routes: routesBasedOnFlags,
    });
    navigation.dispatch(resetStack);
  };
```